# Is it legal to declare a friendship with a forward declared class?

Tags: c++, g++

I have successfully constructed something similar to the following code in visual studio 2008:

```
class OpDevconfigSession;
class DevconfigSession
{
... 
private
   friend class OpDevconfigSession;
};
```

Again, this works quite well with visual studio.  However, if I try to compile the code under g++ version 4.3.2, I get an error message such as:

```
error: friend declaration does not name a class or function
```

I know that standards conformance is not Microsoft's forte so I am wondering if the code that I have written breaks with the standard in some way that I do not yet understand.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code snippet is missing a colon after `private`. After fixing that, it Works For Me™ in g++ (http://codepad.org/XJuyEq9z).

It's also standard - you don't even need the separate forward declaration. See this example from 11.4 of the standard:

```
class X {
    enum { a=100 };
    friend class Y;
};

class Y {
    int v[X::a];        // OK, Y is a friend of X
};
```

Comment: yeah, the missing colon was a transcription error on my part.  I take it, then, that this is a bug that has since been fixed in g++.

Answer (score 1):

The following work for me in `g++ ver 4.4.1`.

```
class OpDevconfigSession;
class DevconfigSession
{
  private:
   friend class OpDevconfigSession;
};
```

I can't see why this might be illegal.